# Custom Setting doesn't get saved after creating a package

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, customsetting

I have some protected custom setting in my salesforce package and I created a VF page for modifying their values . 
When I test that it is working fine but after creating and installing the package , it doesnt work means no data gets saved for custom setting .
Here is the code :

```
 public void saveMyValue()
 {
    newbuilder__customSetting__c settings = newbuilder__customSetting__c.getOrgDefaults();
        settings.newbuilder__URL__c = responseURL;
        settings.newbuilder__User_name__c = userName;
        settings.newbuilder__Token__c = apiKey;
        upsert settings;
    }
```

Comment: data wont be available once you create package and install it in another org.. though you can use [PostInstallScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script_create.htm) and include those values in here..

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using the getInstance() function instead of getOrgDefaults()